# ReactJS how to loop through an object containing arrays to form the desired JSX element

Tags: reactjs, arrays, object, jsx

I am trying to loop through an object where the keys represent the product category and the value represents an array of product objects.

```
{Computer:[{title:Aftershock}],Car:[{title:BMW},{title:Bentley}]}
```

**Data Type**

[image]

How can I loop through the data to prepare the JSX elements to display the products in the following format:

1. For each category create a div
2. Indicate the category name
3. For each product within the category, create it's own product div
4. Indicate the product details

**For example**

```
<div>
  <h1>{category}<h1>
    <div>
     <p>{product.title}<p>
     <p>{product.description}<p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Current code** (But it is filled with syntax error, I cant create the JSX element this way)

```
const compileCategoryOfProducts=(tempCategoryObj)=>{
        let html = [];
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(tempCategoryObj)) {
            let categoryContainerHTML = <Row key={key}><h1>Category</h1>
                {secondLoop(value)}
            </Row>;
            html.push(categoryContainerHTML);
            
        }
        return html;
    }

    const secondLoop=(product)=>{
        let jsxElement = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < product.length; i ++){
            jsxElement.push(<Col key={product[i].id}>
                  <div className="productContainer" >
                        <img src={product[i].image}></img>
                        <p>{product[i].title}</p>
                        <p>Description: {product[i].description}</p>
                        <p>Quantity: {product[i].qty}</p>
                    </div>
            </Col>)
        }
        return jsxElement;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through the object keys using `Object.keys` and then access the nested items. Like this

```
 const [data] = React.useState({
    Computer: [{ title: 'Aftershock' }],
    Car: [{ title: 'BMW' }, { title: 'Bentley' }],
  });
  return (
    <div>
      {Object.keys(data).map((key) => (
        <div>
          <h1>{key}</h1>
          {data[key].map((product) => (
            <div>
              <p>{product?.title}</p>
              <p>{product?.description}</p>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-ihzpwh?file=App.tsx)

Comment: It works, didnt know you can nest map functions like that. Is it possible to create the JSX element outside of the return using for loop iteration though?

Comment: yes. you can move the second loop to a function and return the content and call the function in here

Comment: i have updated my question with my new attempted solution. Do you mind telling me what i did wrongly? it keeps saying product undefined

Comment: please post a separate question